# Operator bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:E \to E'$, be a linear operator where E is Banach. If
$$(\forall x \in E):\;\langle T (x),x \rangle \geq 0$$ 
then show that T is bounded.

Comment: I tryng to use limit uniform principle. But i can $sup\{|<T (x),y> , y \leq 1\}\leq \infity$

Comment: Condition $<T(x),x> \geq 0$ has a name : "positive semi-definite" (abbreviation : psd)

Comment: Do you assume that $E$ is a Banach space, $E'$ its dual and $\langle ., .\rangle$ the dual pairing?

Comment: Yes! E' its dual